# Php i want to remove included file form another include file

Tags: php, include

i want to remove included file form another include file

file1.php:

```
<?php
 include("file2.php");
?>
```

file2.php:

```
<?php
include("anotherfile.php");
?>
```

I dont want to include   anotherfile.php but i just want 
file2.php please help me

Comment: Have you tried... removing the `include` from the `file2.php` file?

Comment: Then you should remove anotherfile.php from file2.php

Comment: i dont want to remove from the file because some other file work with this

Comment: put a check on that file not to be included if not required

Comment: It's very unclear what you're really trying to achieve. Please edit your post and be more specific

Comment: Please make sure to describe your question more complete next time, since now answers that are valid for your original question are receiving downvotes...

Comment: is it possible to include the file starting form one line to another?

Comment: @DiarassoubaSinaly : see my comment to my answer below. Think of splitting `file2.php` into `file2a.php`, `file2b.php` and `file2c.php` if you want to only include `file2b.php`.

Comment: @DiarassoubaSinaly : Do you need more help on this question? Does my answer fit what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: no it is ok i ive found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the second include conditionnal

File1.php

```
$includesAnotherFile = false;
include("file2.php");
```

File2.php

```
if (!isset($includesAnotherFile ) || $includesAnotherFile)
{
    include("anotherfile.php");
}
```

Comment: is it possible to include the file starting form one line to another?

Comment: No, an `include "file.php"` includes the whole file.php. If you want to include only parts of a file you should think of splitting your file in several others.